# Is it ok to make my firebase database public if no accounts are needed in my app?

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

More of a theoretical question, but I am interested in the correct way that public data should be accessed from a Firebase realtime database. This is data that is viewable just by going to a webpage (no sign in needed). In the past I would create an anonymous account, but this seems inefficient (for each viewer of the site) and seems like I might as well set `.read` to `true` in the rules so that no accounts are needed to access the data.

However, it seems like Firebase generally advises against setting `.read` to `true` within the rules, so I was wondering what the correct convention here would be.

Comment: I feel whatever you are trying to implement is fine for the requirements you are having.. Irrespective of Firebase warning..

Comment: Setting .read to true for testing/public consumption of your data is fine. However, PLEASE set .write to requiring authentication or some other form of locking it down - that will prevent data from being written which could crash your app/page/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, setting `.read` to `true` is used for testing purposes, where you don't need authentication and where there are no sensitive data of your users. If the content of your app does not contain data that need to be private, then you can use this settings but if you decide in the future to add authentication and you want to store sensitive data about your users in your database, it's **mandatory** to secure your Firebase database using [Firebase Realtime Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

Hope it helps.